# Reading values inside <map> (XML based config file)

Tags: java, xml, spring, dom, xml-parsing

I have a XML based config file. I declared all the bean, properties, etc there.

Here is my file (XMLFile.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="section" class="com.test.XML.Section">
        <property name="map">
            <map>
                <entry key="1" value="Green" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Here is my Main class (MainClass.java)

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Resource xmlResource = new FileSystemResource("XMLFile.xml");
        BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(xmlResource);
        Color color = (Color)factory.getBean("section");

        System.out.println(color.getMap());
    }
```

And my Section.java

```
public class Color {
    private String map;

    public String getMap() {
        return map;
    }
    public void setMap(String map) {
        this.map = map;
    }
}
```

Now this is my problem. I can't seem to output the entry key and the value.

If I change my XML file property map to this one:

```
<bean id="section" class="com.test.XML.Section">
        <property name="map">
            <value>Green</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I get the output which is `Green`.

What I am trying to do is to get the key and value like an object. And I'm stuck on this one.

I want to get the object like: `color.getId()` and `color.getValue()` using this type of declaration:

```
<bean id="section" class="com.test.XML.Section">
        <property name="map">
            <map>
                <entry key="1" value="Green" />
            </map>
        </property>
```

Is this possible? How can I achieve this?

Comment: this post using DOM parser may help you [link](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)

Comment: I can't seem to output when it comes to mapping part.
<bean id="section" class="com.test.XML.Section">
        <property name="map">
            <map>
                <entry key="1" value="Green" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>